# Remix IDE Solidity Locals

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

I'm having an issue where Solidity Locals doesn't show all the local variables of the function I'm debugging.

In the real code represented by the test code below only **_theirId**, **_myId** and **myScore** show in the locals panel.

In fact whatever I try in terms of variable declaration order only 3 local variables ever show up.

Anyone else having similar issues?

```
function test(uint _theirId, uint _myId ) external onlyOwnerOf(_testId) {

int myScore;

int theirScore;

TestStruct storage myStruct = tests[_myId];

TestStruct storage theirStruct = tests[_theirId];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out what the issues was.

It seems the **onlyOwnerOf(_testId)** modifier was preventing the debugger from displaying all the local variables from the function.

As a workaround I temporarily removed this to debug.